# How to setup things in local to run ABAP Programs

Tags: eclipse-plugin, abap-adt

I wanted to run ABAP programs in my local. So far I tried to setup SAP NetWeaver for ABAP, and also tried to install ADT in my eclipse but I couldn't proceed with any of these.

EDIT: I tried to follow the steps mentioned [here](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/abap-environment-trial-onboarding.html) but I got an error while adding ABAP Development Tools from https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/latest to Eclipse. This was the error message:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>
> Software being installed: ABAP Core Development Tools (Developer Edition) 3.36.0 (com.sap.adt.core.devedition.feature.group 3.36.0)
>
> Missing requirement: ADT Blue SDK (UI) 3.36.0 (com.sap.adt.blues.core.ui 3.36.0) requires 'osgi.bundle; ...

Can you please suggest what needs to be downloaded to run the same?

What I already have is SAP universal Id (Trial Account).

Comment: I tried to follow the steps mentioned here
https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/abap-environment-trial-onboarding.html
but i got an error while adding ABAP Development Tools from https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/latest to eclipse.

this was the error message
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: ABAP Core Development Tools (Developer Edition) 3.36.0 (com.sap.adt.core.devedition.feature.group 3.36.0)
  Missing requirement: ADT Blue SDK (UI) 3.36.0 (com.sap.adt.blues.core.ui 3.36.0) requires 'osgi.bundle;  ...

Comment: Thanks. Your comment was merged into your question. You may delete your comment now.